# Facing error while running application on webswing

Tags: webswing

I deployed new application on webswing working on windows but it giving me this error:
2023-04-27 14:52:20,307 WARN [qtp1288141870-9279] (AbstractResourceHandler.java:257) Failed to parse URI [/static/media/webswing basic default.2e2b2386.svg]!

I tried changing file location, but didnt worked.